# sending data from one sublayout to another in sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm having a hard time building a filtering system in Sitecore 7.

I have 2 sublayouts, on the same level of the page.

Sublayout A is a sidebar that contains a list of checkboxes and has an event that populates a List with the selected values. 
Sublayout B displays a set of items.

What I would like to do, is send the populated List from sublayout A to sublayout B in order to filter the items list based on what the user selected. 
I was able to do this by passing the data through Session, but this is not an optimal way of handling that data.

I've tried defining a property for sublayout A and loading the list there, but I can't get the exact instance of sublayout A from sublayout B in order to read the populated property. 
Also, trying to Page.FindControl("IdOfSomeElementFromSublayoutA") always returns null in Sublayout B. Even though I've casted Page as the .aspx page that contains both Sublayouts.

I'm using Sitecore 7 Update 2.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is by raising (and subscribing to) events using the `Sitecore.Events.Event` class.  Your sidebar sublayout would raise an event using something like the following within a button's click event handler:

```
Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent("YourEventName", new YourEventArgsClass { Property = "SomeValue" });
```

then in the other sublayout you would need to have the following set up in order to handle the event:

```
public partial class YourOtherSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private System.EventHandler eventHandlerRef;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventHandlerRef = EventHandlerMethod;
        Sitecore.Events.Event.Subscribe("YourEventName", eventHandlerRef);
    }

    protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (eventHandlerRef != null)
        {
            Sitecore.Events.Event.Unsubscribe("YourEventName", eventHandlerRef);
        }
    }

    private void EventHandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Note: it is important to keep the Page_Unload code there otherwise you will see the EventHandler method being called multiple times.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast response. I'll try this method and let you know how it went, though it seems to be quite a bit of work involved considering this should be a trivial task imo.

Comment: Your other option is to merge the two user controls together, but that may not fit with your desired sublayout structure?  This is the cleanest way I've found of solving this problem and has the advantage of keeping everything loosely coupled.

Comment: It's not a trivial task, this actually makes it more trivial than it should be. As mdresser says, this makes it extremely loosely coupled and allows your controls to me moved around, added in any placeholder in any layout. You'll have to do it using an eventing system of some sort.

Comment: This worked like a charm and it's actually a lot less work than it seemed. It brings a lot of flexibility! The custom event args class could be reused to send data from any control to another as long as you follow a naming convention to keep it readable.

It's worth noting that in order to retrieve the data from the subscribed event I've used:

`if (e != null)
      {
        var filtersHolder = Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameter(e, 0) as CustomEventArgs;
      }`

This article helped also: [link](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/decoupling-through-the-sitecore-event-pool/)

Comment: When I said it's a trivial task I meant it in the sence of something that usually occurs a lot during the development of a project. To bad Sitecore documentation is full of general stuff that they repeat over and over again and really lacks some real use cases.

Comment: If it's just plain data, you could perhaps use HttpContext.Current.Items (valid for each request) or HttpContext.Current.Session (valid for a users session) or perhaps ASP.Net caching

Comment: Sure, agree the documentation can be a little too general sometimes and good use cases like this would be very beneficial for everyone.